# How to install Local db when you have SQL Server 2012 Express?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, localdb

My system is not allowing me to add Local DB and prompt me a message that a higher version is already available, so do I need to do to get Local Db in my system?

Do I need to uninstall the SQL Server 2012 Express first?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to install LocalDB from the MS SQL Express 2012 installer.

Comment: any links for the same?

Comment: He.. sure: http://bit.ly/1r17ROf BTW 2014 is available as well and is (also) newer.